# $lookup gets all users

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB(Atlas) in my project and I want to use aggregate. but I have a problem getting data.

I have two collections.

```
users:{
  username:'test',
  full_name:'test'
}

profiles:{
  avatar:''
}
```

I use this code to search users by input query

```
const searchedUser = await User.aggregate([
      {
        $search: {
          index: 'User',
          text: {
            query: `${query}`,
            path: {
              wildcard: '*',
            },
            fuzzy: {
              maxEdits: 2,
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          full_name: true,
          username: true,
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'profiles',
          localField: 'user',
          foreignField: 'id',
          as: 'avatar',
        },
      },

    ]);
```

but I get all user avatars in the array for each user. I just wanna only that user avatar.

Profile Collection Sample[image]

User Collection sample
[image]

Comment: can you provide a sample data of both collections

Comment: hi, sorry to respond late I added two images.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a projection with `$arrayElemAt` after your `$lookup` like this:

```js
const searchedUser = await User.aggregate([{
        $search: {
            index: 'User',
            text: {
                query: `${query}`,
                path: {
                    wildcard: '*',
                },
                fuzzy: {
                    maxEdits: 2,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            full_name: true,
            username: true,
        },
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'profiles',
            localField: 'user',
            foreignField: 'id',
            as: 'avatar',
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            full_name: true,
            username: true,
            avatar: {
                $arrayElemAt: ["$avatar", 0]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it returns the user image but if one user doesn't have any images return other user images.